# Why is event.stopImmediatePropagation() working in all browsers except IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events, stoppropagation

After some testing I'm noticing that `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` does not work in IE (per usage below). However, it works in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Opera. What gives?

See **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johntrepreneur/hbKMS/5/)** to reproduce in IE (test fiddle in other browsers to see it work).

**fiddle Javascript:**

```
$(function(){
   
    $('#text').focus(function(event){
        $('#text').val('Use the button to test this.');
    });
    
    $('#button').click(function(event){
        
        // remove all handlers
        $('#text').off('focus');
        
        // now add this other handler in first position
        $('#text').one('focus', function(event){
            $('#text').val('Yay it works! stopImmediatePropagation works in your browser!!');
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        });
        
        // now add a handler in the 2nd position that shouldn't get run
        $('#text').focus(function(event){
            $('#text').val('Oh No! stopImmediatePropagation failed to work in your browser!!');
        });
        
        // now set the focus to test it
        $('#text').focus();
    });
});
```

**fiddle html:**

```
<input id='button' type="button" value="Start Test"/>
<input id='text' style='width:400px;' />
```

Comment: Not sure, and I'm without easy IE access to test. This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446482/how-can-i-mimic-the-behaviour-of-stopimmediatepropagation-without-using-jquer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE has supported stopImmediatePropgation since IE 9 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975461(v=vs.85).aspx), but jquery is the problem.

The jquery version used in your code is not working. This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hbKMS/6/) works perfectly in IE, and the code is exactly the same. The ONLY difference is that it uses jQuery 1.9.1 instead of jQuery 1.8.3

Comment: Nice. Glad it was something simple.