# How to stop event propagation when eventListener attached to same elements in IE 8?

Tags: javascript, events, stoppropagation

How can I stop executing other event handlers **with pure javascript** in case if they are attached to same element in IE8?

I can  stop event propagation with [Event.stopImmediatePropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation) method, but **it's not supported by IE8**.

```js
// document.getElementById('my-elem').attachEvent('click', firstHandler); 
document.getElementById('my-elem').addEventListener('click', firstHandler);
// document.getElementById('my-elem').attachEvent('click', secondHandler); 
document.getElementById('my-elem').addEventListener('click', secondHandler);


function firstHandler(ev){
  ev.stopPropagation();
  alert('1');
}

function secondHandler(ev){
  ev.stopPropagation();
  alert('2');
}
```

```html
<div id="my-elem">
  How to stop propagation ?
</div>
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15351925/1169519) says, that jQuery 1.9.1 has implemented `stopImmediatePropagation` also in older IEs. Hence it's possible, but jQuery has heavily modified event handling model, it might be hard to emulate it with vanilla JS.

Comment: Thanks @Teemu, probably need to point that i am looking for js solution in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simplified (and probably error prone) polyfill/shim. Capture the original attachEvent/detachEvent methods, and create new ones that will check a flag.

Also it will only prevent events that were attached before the one calling stopImmediatePropagation.

```js
if (!Event.prototype.stopImmediatePropagation) {
  (function() {
    var attachEvent = Element.prototype.attachEvent,
        detachEvent = Element.prototype.detachEvent;

    Element.prototype.attachEvent = function(type, callback) {
      attachEvent.call(this, "on"+type, function(event) {
        if (!event.immediatePropagationStopped) {
          callback(event);
        }
      });
    };

    Element.prototype.detachEvent = function(type, callback) {
      detachEvent.call(this, type, callback);
    };
  }());

  Event.prototype.stopImmediatePropagation = function() {
    this.immediatePropagationStopped = true;
  };
}

document.getElementById("test").attachEvent("click",function(e){
  console.log("hi");
});
document.getElementById("test").attachEvent("click",function(e){
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  console.log("hi2");
});
document.getElementById("test").attachEvent("click",function(e){
  console.log("hi3");
});
```

```html
<div id="test">Click me</div>
```

While this did work in the IE 8 emulation mode in my IE 11 browser, as I mentioned earlier this is simplified. So it doesn't do much error checking and other needed checks. Find a proper polyfill for add/removeEventListener, preventDefault, stopPropagation, stopImmediatePropagation if you want production usable code.

Modernizr lists [ES5 DOM SHIM](https://github.com/termi/ES5-DOM-SHIM) as having a polyfill for stopImmediatePropagation so it might have polyfills for the others