# JQuery is not working properly on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm dealing with a code which is working fine on all browsers except IE(Internet explorer).

```
function calculateTotal(rowid, event) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"${createLink(action:'adjustTax', controller:'contractChargeTypeGrid')}",
            success:function (data, status, response) {
                if (data.adjustTax == true) {
                    showNoticeMessages(["${il.message(value: 'taxes.exist.adjust.accordingly')}"], showAdjustmentForAdd);
                } else {
                    showAdjustmentDialog();
                }
            }
        });
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
    }

function showAdjustmentForAdd() {
        if (!isNewRecord) {
            showAdjustmentDialog();
        }
    }

function showAdjustmentDialog(rowid) {
        var modalUrl = "${createLink(action:'chargeAdjustment', controller:'contractChargeTypeGrid')}";
        var editedRows = getNumEditedRows("chargeDetails");
        if (!adjustmentFlag) {
            openPopup(modalUrl, 'Reason for Adjustment', '', '', function () {
                adjustmentFlag = true
            });
        }
    }
```

Here issues is when showNoticeMessages statement is getting executed, there one notification message is getting popup but before closing the popup window, submit action is getting executed.
Expected result: We should wait for the user to cancel the popup button and then again press the submit button and then action should be called.

Please check the code and let me know if we can make any changes to run this code with our expectation.

Thanks

Comment: How and where are you using `calculateTotal()`?

Comment: That is being called on the edit of one column under the grid. Please find below the code                                                                   <grid:column title="Total Due" width="200" name="totalDue" class="numeric" format="currency"
                 editable="${contractChargeDetailFlag.editAmount ? 'true' : 'false'}" onEditSuccess="calculateTotal"/>     When we are going to edit this field and before tab out,directly clicking on the submit button.

Comment: Can you show us the actual code that is sent to the browser (View/Source in the browser)?  This looks like the `"${....}"` things are probably being replaced by something else before being sent to the browser.  We need to see what the browser is actually trying to execute.  And, where does `openPopup()` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made async = flase and which resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are trying to use a version of ie that is lower than 9

support for event.stopImmediatePropagation();
is only available for IE9 and above

see previous answers:

[Why is event.stopImmediatePropagation() working in all browsers except IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15351772/why-is-event-stopimmediatepropagation-working-in-all-browsers-except-ie)

Comment: I'm using IE 9.0.8112.16421

Comment: are there any errors displayed in the developer console?